# Why are subfigures stacked when I want them side-by-side?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want two images side by side and I'm currently using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./0_intro/img/cost_breakdown.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:cost_breakdown} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./0_intro/img/cost_breakdown_forecast.png}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:cost_breakdown_forecast}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\emph{Source: DOE SSL Roundtable and Workshop attendees}}
\label{fig:costs_BD_FC}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Images are grouped staked.]

I played changing the width of the images and it did not work.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I heard that the subfigure package has been obsolete for nearly a decade.

Comment: Using the subcaption package and the mwe package (for example images), it worked just fine.

Comment: as i see in the code there is 3 images not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with **subcaption**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:cost_breakdown} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
   \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:cost_breakdown_forecast}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\emph{Source: DOE SSL Roundtable and Workshop attendees}}
\label{fig:costs_BD_FC}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:cost_breakdown} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:cost_breakdown_forecast}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\emph{Source: DOE SSL Roundtable and Workshop attendees}}
\label{fig:costs_BD_FC}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To avoid having the subfigures become stacked on top of each other, it is important to not have any empty line between them.